# xtag issue with special characters

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jstl

I'm using x tag to parse through an xml that has special characters such as é Here is my xml

```
<stack>
<data title="thé"/>
</stack>
```

here is the xtag that prints out the output

```
<x:out select="@title" />
```

the view source of the page displays this output

```
theé
```

and visually this is displayed by the browser

```
theÃ©
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: my apologies here is the xml
<stack>
<data title="theé"/>
</stack>



here is the xtag statement that I'm using
<x:out select="@title" />

Comment: edit your question; highlight the code/xml sections and hit the {} button to mark them as code.

Comment: Does "xtag" / "x tag" mean "XML Tags" of JSTL? Also, why is this question tagged XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

Since the source view shows the character correctly, the problem is probably not with your JSTL XML tag expression. Instead, it might have to do with the content-type that the page is labeled with.

Single non-ASCII characters getting rendered as two characters (the first is typically an A with some sort of accent) is a pretty sure sign that UTF-8 content is getting treated as ISO-8859-1, or something similar. I'm not an expert in this area, but the browser needs to be told that the content you're serving is in UTF-8. So check the [meta content-type](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) of your output. It should specify UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
```

Comment: that is exactly what I have on top of the page

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">